# css to avoid extra space due to page break in outlook mail , while sending mail from mailchimp?

Tags: css, mailchimp, outlook-2007

while sending mail from mailchimp to outlook mail, I'm getting extra space(may be page break).Below is my html skeleton,which i'm sending.
**When i keep on adding image2 inside "Td32" in below skeleton i'm finding an extra space between images.**
Please can anybody suggest me how to avoid page break or unwanted space?

```
<table class="T1">
<tr>
<td>
<table class="T2"></table>
<table class="T3">
  <tr><td class="Td31">Text</td>
       <td class="Td32"><div class="repetableimg1">image1</div>
                        <div class="repetableimg2">image2</div>
       </td></tr>
</table>
<table class="T4"></table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to eliminate the whitespace (linefeeds, etc) between the closing `>` and opening `<`... depending on your platform, you should be able to use a regex similar to this...  `input.replace(/\>[\s\r\n]+\</g, '><')`

Also the table:

```
<table 
  border=0 
  cellpadding=0 
  cellspacing=0
  style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;"
>
  <tr>
     <td style="padding:0">
       ...
```

Email rendering is fairly inconsistent, and best to use 1998 rules regarding your html markup and styling.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I updated my code.  still my spacing problem is not solved.

Comment: Added reference to the table... sorry, forgot... and may want to ensure border is 0 on the image, if it's in an anchor element.  Don't use "classes" on your tables, you need to inline the styles.

Comment: i tried with these options also but not able to overcome page break.Also tried below css page-break-before ,page-break-after ,page-break-inside ,still im finding problem.

Comment: `<table style="page-break-before:always; ...`  Do *NOT* use classes, also, page breaks aren't always respected, period... there may not be anything you can do about it, other than making your images larger/smaller as an experiment.